# What is the best approach to holding multiple WebSocket clients in memory in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement a way to hold multiple WebSocket client connections at a time. The reason for this is because I would like to start and stop these connections through API endpoints as well as send messages and receive messages.

For context, I am wanting to connect to multiple Remote Consoles ([RCON](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol)) to receive and send messages to them. Sometimes the server hosting the RCON may restart, and being able to reconnect is vital.

My current solution allows me to start, stop and send messages, **however the EventHandlers do not fire** (except for the opening of the WebSocket).

```cs
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace Rcon;

public interface IWebSocketManager
{
    void AddWebSocketConnection(string key, WebSocket webSocket);

    void RemoveWebSocketConnection(string key);

    void Send(string key, string message);

    WebSocket? GetWebSocketConnection(string key);
}

public class WebSocketManager : IWebSocketManager
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocket> _connections = new();

    public void AddWebSocketConnection(string key, WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        _connections.TryAdd(key, webSocket);
    }

    public void RemoveWebSocketConnection(string key)
    {
        _connections.TryRemove(key, out _);
    }

    public void Send(string key, string message)
    {
        if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out WebSocket? webSocket))
            webSocket.Send(message);
    }

    public WebSocket? GetWebSocketConnection(string key)
    {
        _connections.TryGetValue(key, out WebSocket? connection);

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Registering the dependency:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IWebSocketManager, WebSocketManager>()
```

I am adding it to the concurrent dictionary with the following method, using the IWebSocketManager dependency:

```cs
public void AddConnection(ConnectionDetails connectionDetails)
    {
        WebSocket ws = new(connectionDetails.ConnectionString);

        ws.OnOpen += (_, _) =>
        {
            // Fires
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Connected to WebSocket. Url: {connectionDetails.Ip}:{connectionDetails.Port}");
        };

        ws.OnClose += (_, _) =>
        {
            // DOES NOT FIRE
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Disconnected from WebSocket. Url: {connectionDetails.Ip}:{connectionDetails.Port}");

                _webSocketManager.RemoveWebSocketConnection(connectionDetails.CreateWSMKey());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // TODO
            }
        };

        ws.OnMessage += (_, e) =>
        {
            // DOES NOT FIRE
            Console.WriteLine("Received message from WebSocket");
        };

        ws.Connect();

        _webSocketManager.AddWebSocketConnection(connectionDetails.CreateWSMKey(), ws);
    }
```

I would like to make calling Send() on WebSockets incredibly easy as exampled below:

```cs
    private readonly IWebSocketManager _webSocketManager;

    public SocketController(IWebSocketManager webSocketManager)
    {
        _webSocketManager = webSocketManager;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("sendsocketmessage/{message}")]
    public ActionResult SendSocketMessage(string message)
    {
        ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = new("localhost", 3000, "password");

        var socket = _webSocketManager.GetWebSocketConnection(connectionDetails.CreateWSMKey());
        
        socket?.Send(message);

        return Ok();
    }
```

The above does work with my current implementation. But none of this matters if `OnMessage` event doesn't trigger.

The approach I am taking does not feel right, but it almost works... How can I improve my solution to this problem. Is RabbitMQ a good option, I think it will remove some of the functionality that I want however.

Comment: Your events have to be registered using an instance which is the property "_connections[index]".  So your method AddConnection needs a parameter for _connection[i].